# Invalid value io.confluent.connect.s3.format.protobuf.ProtobufFormat for configuration format.class

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
    -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/sink-s3-voluble/config \
    -d '
 {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
                "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
                "tasks.max": "1",
                "topics": "cats",
                "s3.region": "ap-south-1",
                "s3.bucket.name": "testbucketkafka",
                "flush.size": "65536",
                "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
                "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
                "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
        "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
        "transforms": "AddMetadata",
        "transforms.AddMetadata.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.AddMetadata.offset.field": "_offset",
        "transforms.AddMetadata.partition.field": "_partition"
        }
```

***The error given is Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid value io.confluent.connect.s3.format.protobuf.ProtobufFormat for configuration format.class: Class io.confluent.connect.s3.format.protobuf.ProtobufFormat could not be found.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}***

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct. There is no `config.format=ProtobufFormat` configuration

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/configuration_options.html#connector

Set `format.class` to a supported value.